# Does changing the background also change the padding of a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, background, padding, android-linearlayout

I have the following `LinearLayout`. What I don't understand is if I set the background to another image, the padding information are reset. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/aPanel"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bkground"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" android:paddingRight="15dp"> 

     <!-- some children here -->
     </LinearLayout>
```

I see the position of the children get shifted when I change the background drawable of the `LinearLayout` *aPanel*.

Comment: What is your evidence that "the padding information are reset"? In other words, what are your actual symptoms?

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890379/android-setbackgroundresource-discards-my-xml-layout-attributes - the padding simply gets reset after setBackgroundResource() is called (possibly related to only 9-patch backgrounds).

Answer (score 43):

This is the default behavior when changing the background `Drawable` on a `View`.  According to Romain Guy, one of the Android developers, "The reason why setting an image resets the padding is because 9-patch images can encode padding."  See his full answer in a [similar question](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg09595.html).

The fix is to reset the padding in code each time you change the background drawable.

Answer (score 20):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890379/setbackgroundresource-discards-my-xml-layout-attributes) is a similar question.

in short, the answer would be :

```
public static void setViewBackgroundWithoutResettingPadding(final View v, final int backgroundResId) {
    final int paddingBottom = v.getPaddingBottom(), paddingLeft = v.getPaddingLeft();
    final int paddingRight = v.getPaddingRight(), paddingTop = v.getPaddingTop();
    v.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResId);
    v.setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
}
```

The reason for the padding being reset is because the drawable might be a 9-patch drawable .

Comment: You can also set background using selector with proper set of states. Then you don't have to restore paddings

Comment: @ArkadiuszCieśliński Sure. depends on the case and your needs

Comment: @androiddeveloper I had to post a runnable to the view to make the padding work, why is this happening?

Comment: @zero.zero.seven I don't remember such an issue. Maybe you should post about it, and show some code to give clues about the reason for this. Maybe it's also best to create a tiny app sample to show your issue.

Comment: @androiddeveloper if the following information didn't help, I will create a thread about it, I do the following operations on the TextView:
set backround,
set text,
set padding on four sides,
and set typeface;

and the bottom/right padding get nasty sometimes, I tried the runnable, so the issue happens less! but it's still out there on some items of the listview

Comment: @zero.zero.seven Sounds odd. Have you tried using a 9-patch , if it's even possible on your case?

Answer (score 4):

You can use shape to set the background with single colour or image and apply padding like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dip"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip"/>
</shape>
```