# Android: calling textview.setBackgroundResource twice changes the textview size

Tags: android, resize, textview, background-image

I have a nine-patched image, which I set the background for my textview during activity.onCreate(). Textview has WRAP_CONTENT layout for both height+width. It's created from code, not from XML.

```
_btnCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_off);
```

This works fine.
I have an other nine-patched image, same size, only difference is it's color.
Now if I call setBackgroundResource later with the other image, it will increase the height of the textview, almost to double. This other call happens from the textview.onClick()

```
_btnCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_on);
```

If I call it again (clicking again in the textview), no effect. Which is good, and I suppose it to happen for the first click as well.
So:

```
Activity.onCreate()
{
    btnCurrent= new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btnCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_hs_off);

    btnCurrent.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5);
    btnCurrent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    btnCurrent.setText( GetString(id) );        
    btnCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);

}

onClick()
{
    _btnCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_on);
}


onCreate();  // -> called by Android during startup -> OK
....
onClick();   // called when user clicks on it -> btnCurrent has double height
....
onClick();   // called when user clicks again -> btnCurrent has same double height, no change in size
....
onClick();   // called when user clicks again -> btnCurrent has same double height, no change in size
```

I tried to set the _btnHSCurrent.setBackgroundResource(0);  before setting the new image, but does not help.

Why does this happen?

@Edit

I did:
_btnCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_off); during the Activity.onCreate().

Then in the textview.onClick(), I call:

_btnCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_on);

and this will double the height. Clicking again, again, again, does not change the size anymore, only at first click.

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you mind to put here to two 9-patch images?

Comment: seems your problem with the 2nd image (button_menu_on)

Comment: Can you show the xml part of your textview ?

Comment: @ArnaldoGaspar: I do not have it in XML, I create the TextView from code in the onCreate().`TextView retval = new TextView(this);
`LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
`retval.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_menu_hs_off);
`retval.setTextColor(0xff000000);
`retval.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5);
`retval.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
`retval.setText( GetString(id) );  
`retval.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: @MoshErsan: what problem can you see with the 2nd image (white)?

Comment: retval.setIncludeFontPadding(false) works?

Comment: @ArnaldoGaspar:  setIncludeFontPadding(false) -> no change

Comment: Check *all* your drawables folders. You may have a differently-sized variant of *one* of the button background images in drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-nodpi, etc.

Comment: @ReubenScratton, nope these 2 png exist only in the res/drawable.

Comment: What happens if you swap the images around? Does the button start big and then get small when clicked?

Comment: @ReubenScratton: same behavior with swapped images

Comment: I FOUND IT, FINALLY :)
The problem is, calling `setBackgroundResource()` again seems to erase the padding. During the creation of the textview, I call `setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5)` after the `setBackgroundResource()`. If I call `setPadding()` after the second `setBackgroundResource()` in the `onClick()` (just like during the creation of the textview), it's fine again. Works, no height change. THANKS all your hints, helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886140/does-changing-the-background-also-change-the-padding-of-a-linearlayout

Consider this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a similar issue I had with padding. After calling `setBackgroundResource` the padding seems to change, not using the values I configured in `styles.xml`. The effect looks the same as if the size has changed, but in fact it is the padding.

My workaround is to call `setPadding` on the button after changing the background, for example:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_add);
button.setPadding(10, 15, 10, 15);
```

It's not great but it works.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I just found the same solution, see my last comment under the question. Yes, this was the problem, `setBackgroundResource`
ruins the padding. Marking this as the solution

Comment: But you're using ninepatches, so the padding should be specified as part of the image. You should only specify padding in XML or via setPadding() when *not* using a ninepatch...

Comment: @ReubenScratton: That's also something to consider...however being lazy it is simpler to play with `setPadding()` than editing images

Comment: @ReubenScratton the padding inherent in the nine-patch is one thing, the padding you can add around your *content* is another. Ideally the nine-patch should have minimal padding and let the user control the padding in xml or Java code.

Comment: That's crazy, must be a bug, it's hardly intentional. Anyway, I had the same problem but it was when I set the background resource for a `RelativeLayout`, which is weird because I thought those things couldn't have any padding. In any case, calling `setPadding(0,0,0,0)` after setting the resource fixed it!