# Set padding for textview works only after setting background resource - Android

Tags: android, textview

Setting the background resource to a drawable xml for a textview after setting its padding doesn't pad the textview, but vice versa works. How ?

Example

works

```
   textView.setBackgroundResource(borderColor);
   textView.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

doesn't work

```
   textView.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
   textView.setBackgroundResource(borderColor);
```

Comment: Use layout params and set that on textview

Comment: I wanted to know why it doesn't work when we set the padding before setting the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you change the background, the padding is reset. This is the default behaviour.
You can find more about this:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886140/does-changing-the-background-also-change-the-padding-of-a-linearlayout)
and 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095196/whered-padding-go-when-setting-background-drawablehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095196/whered-padding-go-when-setting-background-drawable)